# how to design program to accommodate unique (but similar) XML data passed by partners

Tags: xml, database, import

I have a system used by local jails to track inmates, charges, and bail bond amounts.  Each local jail sends me this information in an XML or delimited text file and I load it into Db tables so that it can be accessed online.

Jail A sends me this data:

```
inmate-id   int
first-name  string
last-name  string
charge    string
amount  money
```

Jail B sends me this:

```
inmateID  string
fname   string
lname  string
addr   string
city  string
state  string
zip  string
inmate_charge string
bond_amount  money
```

Jail C sends me similar info to A and B but maybe calls their data

```
first
last
address
```

Jail D may also be similar but they also pass

```
home-phone
cell-number
```

There is no predicting what Jail E will be sending until they sign up as a customer.

Is there a way I can design my import program to be flexible enough so that as I add new jails I can configure it to accommodate the new jail's data that may be similar to another jail but will be unique?

Also, how could I design my database tables so that I can store Data that will come from all jails like inmate ID and names in 1 table and more unique data in other tables?  Would I even need to do that?

Thanks for any guidance you can provide.

Comment: 1) Doesn't database volumetry matters? Seems you don't discolse any details on it. 2) Are on line data access per customer based?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you choose an XML format of your own - either one of those you are importing or something different altogether - and write XSLT transforms for each of the sources that will convert the source data into your chosen target format. With data this simple the task should be straightforward once you have an understanding of XSLT.